# DecimalFormat with comma

Tags: java

> DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

this code can help us to convert number with two decimal places String

```
df.format(20.0030) // Result: "20.00"
```

However, if I try this

```
df.format(2000.0030) // Result: "2000.00"
```

And with NumberFormat

```
NumberFormat.getInstnace().format(2000.0030) // Result "2,000.0"
```

Can I have result of 2,000.00 in java ?? (**Comma** and **dot** with **two decimal** places)

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't read the Javadoc to find the `#,##0.00`pattern?

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry dude quite in rush v,v my fault sorry community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by using:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
```